# Empty data in Lumen when testing my API using curl

Tags: laravel, curl, lumen

I have an api endpoint that I'm receiving data via a POST. My controller signature looks like this:

`public function handle(Request $request)`

When I go to test my endpoint, I'm running a really basic test like this:

`curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' -d '<XML>data</XML>' http://URL/api`

When I `\Log::debug($request)` I get nothing. Even if I `\Log::debug($_POST)` I still don't get anything.

Is there a filter that's turned on by default in Lumen? I'm kind of at a loss here. Maybe my curl statement is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the XML in the request body. Therefore, to retrieve the content of the request, you have to use `$request->getContent` like this:

```
public function handle(Request $request)
{
    \Log::debug($request->getContent());
}
```

Comment: @jeffkolez No problem :)

Comment: @jeffkolez Please mark my answer as correct when you have the time. Have a nice day :)

Comment: My bad, I thought I had. Done now.